# How to read character stream and write in to file when we run application in kernel module in O.S X?

Tags: macos, kernel, kernel-extension

My application will be build and packed to run in kernel mode on OS X.Its showing symbols not found when i run the instrumented application in kernel mode.This is obvious because standard libraries are not available.

Please can any one help me in reading character stream and write in to file when we run application in kernel module in O.S X.

Comment: So where's the problem? You need to use something like [`vnode_open`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/kernel/1562149-vnode_open) to open the file, [`vn_rdwr`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/kernel/1562098-vn_rdwr?language=objc) to read/write the file. You really want a good book for this, as programming the kernel is very different to programming userland code.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here by creating a kernel module?

Comment: The quick answer is *don't use standard libraries* when you are programming in kernel mode.  What do you want to read? where from? have you a testable code snippet that can be compiled and tested by us to make a diagnostic?  User space doesn't distinguish a file from a data stream coming from a network connection, but kernel does.